# Java - Best way to open a ton a files and search for a word?

Tags: java, search, bufferedreader

I am searching a directory with about 450 files, each file around 20kb. Here is my method:

```
public void search(String searchWord) throws IOException
{
    this.directoryPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(this.directoryString);
    this.fileListStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(this.directoryPath);
    int fileCount = 0;
    for(Path path : this.fileListStream)
    {
        String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
        if(!fileName.startsWith("."))
        {
            BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(fileName + ": " + line);
            }
            fileCount++;
            br.close();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("File Count: " + fileCount);
}
```

My goal is to go word by word and find a match for searchWord and print out the line number and the file name it was found in.

My problem is that I'm wondering if I should split the line into an array and search the array for the word and add it to a list. Or should I scan the entire file into an array of words and then search for the words and add them to a list? Or does it even matter? Also, if there is a better way to do this, please let me know! I'm trying to do this as efficient as possible due to limited resources.

Comment: You shouldn't save anything into arrays unless you need to. Just check as you read the `File` if the word is equal to your `searchWord`

Comment: Where you can win is not to use naive searching but something like the Aho-Corasick algorithm, that pre-compiles your search string into a structure that can then be used to efficiently trawl through all the files.

Comment: why dont you try apache solr something

Comment: If the files are organized alphabetically you can use a more efficient search algorithm.

Comment: And if you have to perform lots of searches for different words on the same files, then indexing (concordance) is the way to go. So there is no single best way, there are many ways that are good for certain scenarios but not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be looking word-by-word, just read the entire line as a String and then use String.indexOf() method to find if the line contains the word or not.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of this. This works perfectly and it's not overkill for the project I'm working on.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Scanner class to parse files and use its next() method to read each word so you won't require any array or other storage. Try to use multi-threading if possible for each file which can even improve performance.

Comment: As a general rule, multi-threading doesn't speed up IO-bound processes, in fact it might make them slower.

Comment: It depends on the system. As an example, "I/O bound" just means "one thread spends most of its time waiting for I/O completion instead of using the CPU", but does not mean that "we've hit the system I/O bandwidth limit", then IMO having multiple threads (or asynchronous I/O) might improve performance (by enabling more than one concurrent I/O operation).

Comment: That's why I said it's only a general rule. It doesn't always work, but typically disk I/O deteriorates when you try to read files in different locations (but on the same disk) at the same time.